# Can't login to Ubuntu after installing CUDA

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I want to install CUDA 8.0 in my Ubuntu 16.04.
First I stopped the X server with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
```

Then I installed CUDA 8.0 from the official Nvidia website. (The graphics driver is installed with CUDA).

When I rebooted my Ubuntu, it got stuck in a login loop. What can I do?

Comment: login loop, not reboot loop?  can you get to the text console with `Ctrl+Alt+F3`?

Comment: Yes, I can get to text console with Ctrl+Alt+F1.  And I can login in text console but get login loop in GUI.

Comment: if i were you i'd uninstall the CUDA+driver and try to find v8 through official ubuntu packages (check backports, or a PPA if necessary).  if nothing else, grab [CUDA v8 source package from 16.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/yakkety/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) and build the package on your own system as a local backport.  same with latest nvidia driver.

Comment: as far as troubleshooting the login loop, that's probably an X config breaking on the driver you installed, and should be easier to get working once you have a proper installation.  (stop + disable lightdm, try starting X from console, tweak configs as needed, reenable lightdm once it's all working.)

Comment: Nvidia's drivers through their website are broken from experience. I instead install through official ubuntu packages first, and when I install CUDA I skip installing the driver. The answers below helped me since I swapped out an old card for a newer one and got a login loop because the drivers installed were incompatible with my newer card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I successfully install CUDA 8.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. I think the main issue is the graphic driver.

1. I re-instell Ubuntu because I can't login even after I remove nvidia driver and cuda.
2. I change the graphic driver to nvidia driver through `Additional Drivers`. In my ubuntu, it's `NVIDIA binary driver-version 367.57 from nvidia-367(proprietary,tested)`.
3. I install cuda 8.0 follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04) without the nvidia driver in cuda.

Answer (score 3):

Before you do anything else, write these two commands for escaping from a login loop on a piece of paper, so if you get stuck in a login loop when booting you will be able to do something about it.

- `sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) .Xauthority`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Also write down the link to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634) which has more detailed information about how to get unstuck from a login loop.

---

Your problem may have been caused by the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver that is bundled with the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit from official NVIDIA CUDA Downloads website. So try using the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver and NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit from the default Ubuntu repositories.

The NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit package from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories is version 7.5 which is not as up-to-date as the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 8.0 package from the official NVIDIA CUDA Downloads website, but is it more stable and reliable. The same goes for the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, *nvidia-346* or *nvidia-352* or whatever other nvidia driver version is recommended for your hardware in Step 4. of the following instructions.

1. Bring up a text-only virtual console from the login screen, using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only virtual console which shows you a login prompt. Login to the console at the login prompt with your username and password.
2. Run this command to show a list of cuda packages, that will help you to identify the name of the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit package that you installed.

   ```
   dpkg-query -l cuda*
   ```
3. Uninstall the NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver from a text-only console. The file you used to install the NVIDIA CUDA Tookit from the NVIDIA website should be named something like *cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb*. If so, the command to uninstall it is:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64
   sudo reboot
   ```

   If the file you used to install the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit has a different name or if you installed a different file, then change the name in the above command. If you installed *cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run* file (runfile (local)), then comment so that I can change the command to match this file. The name of the file in the above command has to match exactly with the name of the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit file that you installed.
4. After you reboot, uninstall all the CUDA packages you previously installed. They won't work properly without the NVIDIA proprietary driver from the NVIDIA website, so you will have to install the CUDA packages from the default Ubuntu repositories instead.
5. Identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your system. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   ubuntu-drivers devices
   ```
6. Install the recommended NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver and reboot.

   ```
   sudo apt install <package-name-of-the-recommended graphics-driver> 
   sudo reboot
   ```
7. Install the CUDA packages. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt install libcudart7.5 nvidia-cuda-toolkit
   ```

---

P.S. I hope you didn't change any PATH variables in the terminal after you installed the CUDA package from the official NVIDIA CUDA Downloads website. If you did change the PATH variable from the terminal, please comment and let me know, so I can tell you how to change it back.

Comment: I solved the issue. I think it is nvidia driver that cause the problem. And I list the steps in my answer. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 3):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to a different terminal
- Login
- Uninstall nvidia* packages

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*

- After that, install nvidia-346

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-346

- reboot

Comment: Did you mean F3? F2 and the other terminals work too, of course. That might be specific to newer versions of Ubuntu, though,  I don't have 16.04 available to test.

Comment: Yes Press Ctr + Alt + F3

Comment: This worked for me but I had to reboot after I purged, then installed the drivers once I logged back in.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't try over ubuntu 16.04 but i had same experience with ubuntu 10.04 in which problem is solved by **purging gdm**
Please  follow your cuda installation guide install all the dependencies and before running cuda installer do:

> apt-get purge gdm

Comment: gdm is no longer used in vanilla Ubuntu 16.04. Also before uninstalling the existing login display manager, it would be better to try simply reconfiguring it by following the instructions in my answer. That way if reconfiguring the login display manager works you can login immediately.

Comment: yes gdm is for ubuntu 10, for new version of ubuntu their is lightdm and by purging this i have solved this issue in ubuntu 14 as well.